# Generate bearer token using postman

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, postman

I have registered an application in Azure AD. I selected supported account type as '**Single-tenant**'. I have given permissions like **user.read, openid and profile.**

Now, I am trying to get access token from **Postman**. I have given parameters like below:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/mytenantid/oauth2/v2.0/token
client_id='myapp client id'
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read
&redirect_uri=http://localhost
&grant_type=authorization_code
&client_secret='myapp client secret'
```

**I am getting the below error:**

> AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter:  'code'.\r\nTrace ID:  ffa4ba48-3287-4615-b6a3-aa71ed757400\r\nCorrelation ID: b375f781-2486-40d4-adee-826b9dc440ec\r\nTimestamp: 2022-04-21 12:13:10Z",

I am not understanding what code to give and how to find **code value**.
Can anyone help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To resolve the error, you have to include code parameter in Postman.**

To get that value, try to form an **authorize url** like below:

https://login.microsoftonline.com/yourtenantid/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=yourclientid&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost&response_mode=query&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/user.Read&state=skip_get_token2

And open the above link in browser. In address bar you will get the value of **code**.

[image]

Copy that code value and add that parameter in postman.

Please **Note** that, the code value will work only one time. To get the code value again, you have to *repeat the above process again.*

***I tried in my environment, after adding the code parameter, I got the access token successfully:***

[image]

For more in detail, please **refer** below link:

[Microsoft identity platform and OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow - Microsoft identity platform | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-authorization-code).