# How to work with "Identity Management Systems"?

Tags: database, azure-active-directory

This is my first question, so I hope I don't miss a thing. To be clear from the start: I don't expect an answer which dives deep into detail. This is just about getting a general understanding of how to work with this kind of software.

So I don't know if "Identity Management System" is a suitable term for what I mean but when I talk about Identity Management Systems I think of something like Azure AD, which as far as I know provides e.g. web developers the possibility to integrate a way users can authenticate (including access privilege etc.) on their website.

What I'm quite unsure about is how to work with/ integrate such tools in a project. I will try to make it clear with an example: Assuming I have a website let's say this website is a blog. The blog consist of different posts which are stored in my own database which is connected to the website. The posts are written by different users which authenticate with a tool like Azure AD. The user's data is stored somewhere on a server run by e.g. Microsoft. If I want to display the posts togethere with the name, email.... of the user who wrote them, how would I do this?

- Is it possible to query the user's data directly from the Identity Management System and display it? This does not sound ideal to me as the consequence would be that data the website uses is stored in two different locations.
- Would you kind of copy the user's data from the Identity Management System to the websites database and query it from there? This does not sound like a good solution either because then data would be duplicated.

So whats the "right workflow"?

I appreciate any hints and further information I can get:-)

Answer (score 0):

***AFAIK To get the user's information like name, email etc. you can add these claims while generating the JWT token.***

To generate access token, you have multiple authentication flows such as **[Authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow)**, **[ROPC flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc)**, **[Implicit flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow)**.

To add the **claims** that you need to return with the token, you can make settings like below:

*Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> App Registrations -> Your app -> Token configuration -> Add optional claims*

[image]

When you decode the token via [**JSON Web Tokens - jwt.io**](https://jwt.io/) you can find the user information that you need.

To know how to generate access token, you can refer [***SO Thread***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72017597/generate-bearer-token-using-postman) which I solved it before.